# determine if given PIDL belongs to a specific shell virtual folder ( ex. recycle bin)

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, windows-shell

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Recognize Windows Shell Special Folder (i.e. get its CSIDL) via its pIDL (Now determine if pIDLs are equal with C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3572220/recognize-windows-shell-special-folder-i-e-get-its-csidl-via-its-pidl-now-de)

I have the PIDL of a shell virtual folder how can I compare the PIDL to CSIDL_BITBUCKET ?

Comment: For RecycleBin you can do this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2008/09/18/8956382.aspx